# Does erlang ChicagoBoss webserver support couchdb (couchbase)?

Tags: erlang, couchbase, chicagoboss

I am looking to use erlang ChicagoBoss webserver to develop webapp with Couchbase(Couchdb) as backend. But I don't see adapter for it other than Riak and Mongodb. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't support CouchDB, yet.

You can see the supported DBMS, [here](https://github.com/evanmiller/ChicagoBoss/wiki/Configuration). Apparently, CouchDB will be added in version 1.0. See the roadmap [here](https://github.com/evanmiller/ChicagoBoss/wiki/Roadmap).